# What is the proper way to add optional program arguments to a plist?

Tags: plist, cassandra

This command line usage statement is displayed near the bottom of the [Running Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandra) wiki page.

```
bin/cassandra [-f] [-h] [-p pidfile]
```

Below it, is an example of a Cassandra plist file for Mac OS X 10.6.x.  I’ve only quoted the example’s array of the program arguments for the sake of brevity and clarity.

```
...
<array>
<string>/opt/local/bin/cassandra</string>
<string>-h</string>
</array>
...
```

Now, when it comes to adding the optional [-p pidfile] arguments to the program arguments’ array, is it proper to write the string nodes as?

```
<string>-p</string>
<string>/usr/local/apache/cassandra/0.7.5/runtime/pid.txt</string>
```

Or as?

```
<string>-p /usr/local/apache/cassandra/0.7.5/runtime/pid.txt</string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former.  The latter should work if you omit the space, if `cassandra` uses something compatible with POSIX `getopt()`.